# Terraform resource lifecycle destroy_after_create?

Tags: terraform

Is there an option in terraform configuration that would automatically destroy the resource after its dependents have been created? I am thinking something like destroy_after_create lifecycle which doesn't exist.

I want to delete all Lambda archives (s3 objects) after the Lambda Functions get created. Obviously I can create a script to run "terraform destroy -target" after "apply" completes, however I am looking for something within terraform configuration itself.

Answer (score 1):

To hack your way in Terraform, you can use the following combination:

- [local-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html)
- [null-resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource)
- [AWS CLI - aws s3api delete-object](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/delete-object.html#synopsis)
- [Terraform depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/depends_on.html)

Like this

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
}

resource "null_resource" "delete_lambda" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket,
    # other dependencies ...
  ]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws s3api delete-object --bucket my-bucket --key lambda.zip"
  }
}
```